# Can I get clicked element in jQuery/coffeescript as an argument?

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, click, element

I have this ancient code written in CoffeeScript & Mootools:

```
  pleaseDo:
    "click:relay(#click-me)": @doSomething

  doSomething: (event, element) =>
    console.log event   # shows event
    console.log element # shows element
```

I'm trying to rewrite it to jQuery, and I'm wondering what's the best way of getting the clicked element in jQuery?

```
  pleaseDo:
    $("#click-me").on "click": @doSomething

  doSomething: (event, element) =>
    console.log event   # shows event
    console.log element # undefined
```

I know I could use `event.target`, like:

```
  doSomething: (event) =>
    element = event.target
    console.log event   # shows event
    console.log element # shows event
```

But I don't like how it looks like. Can I somehow get the true "element" as an argument to doSomething function (just like in Mootools)?

Comment: Doesn't this throw an error? That updated `pleaseDo` block is nonsensical.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to do `$(event.target)` or `$(this)`.

Comment: Is that the only way? It looks much worse than in Mootools (especially if I need to repaste it in every function...).

Comment: The point is, event.target returns valid element while $(this) returns the whole class, any idea why might this happen?

Comment: @Wordpressor because you've scoped `doSomething` to the class by using `=>`.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it this way:

```
   $('#click-me').on('click', function(){
     console.log($(this));
   });
```

This will return you the jQuery object so you can then use it like this

```
   $('#click-me').on('click', function(){
      $(this).text('hola');
    });
```

Else, if you want the whole html object using the javascript this

```
   $('#click-me').on('click', function(){
      console.log(this);
   });
```

Comment: Only event.target returns valid element for me, $(this) returns the whole class object, I'm not sure why :(